# Running shell_exec('which java') in PHP return nothing

Tags: java, php, linux

If I run

```
which java
```

from the command line I get the proper input (/usr/java/.../bin/java). However if I run it in a php script:

```
<?
  echo 'java. ' . shell_exec('which java');
  echo 'ls. ' . shell_exec('which ls');
?>
```

nothing gets printed out for which java but I get the proper results for which ls...

Comment: The server process doesn't have it's path environment variable set.

Comment: If I send the hardcoded path it works. I then tried to include it in a bash file script with the environment setup and it didn't work either...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things were needed:

- the full path to the JVM (it wasn't set in the environment)
- " 2>&1" at the end of the command line.

So for example:

```
echo shell_exec('/usr/java/jdk6/bin/java -cp myJars.jar MyMainClass arg1 2>&1");
```

Comment: Thanks, just what I was looking for during the past 30 minutes. Adding the 2>&1 worked. Not sure why though...

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this problem as well. I was trying to determine if the `qrencode` utility is installed on the (any) server, and if not then log/warn/exit gracefully.

Considering the program should always be in a standard path, I prefixed the `which` command with the likely locations of the binary, while still respecting that `$PATH` might be somehow defined on the system. I think you could use this approach with common Java paths, too:

```
shell_exec('PATH="$PATH:/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin" '.
           'which qrencode');
```